# R: can I use a variable i to replace numbers in a series of variables, such as chr1, chr2,chr3...?

Tags: r

I don't want to put them in an array or a list. Is there any symbol (like the '$' in Linux) I can use? Thanks!

Comment: Please show some example and the expected result.

Comment: The poster has obviously not used SO before so I would not be too quick to downvote this unless they do not respond to requests for fixing up the question.

Comment: -1 poster has not responded to requests for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for string interpolation then here are some examples:

**1)**

```
library(gsubfn)

# test data
num <- 7
x <- "The lucky number is $num"

fn$identity(x)
## [1] "The lucky number is 7"
```

**1a)** or it could be done like this:

```
gsubfn(x = x)
## [1] "The lucky number is 7"
```

**2)** Another example which may be closer to what you were looking for:

```
sapply(1:3, function(i) fn$identity("chr$i"))
## [1] "chr1" "chr2" "chr3"
```

**2a)** or

```
sapply(1:3, function(i) gsubfn(x = "chr$i"))
## [1] "chr1" "chr2" "chr3"
```

**3)** If we knew there were exactly three and we had specific numbers to substitute we might prefer:

```
i <- 1; j <- 2; k <- 3
fn$c("chr$i", "chr$j", "chr$k")
## [1] "chr1" "chr2" "chr3"
```

**4)** Of course, in the above examples we could have simply done `paste("The lucky number is", num)` and `paste0("chr", 1:3)` not using string interpolation.

**5)** Also a simple substitution iterated over the indexes would work:  `sapply(1:3, sub, pattern = "!", x = "chr!")`

Comment: It's probably good to disclose your authorship of this package.

Comment: @Thomas curious... why?

Comment: @TylerRinker "Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers." http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: interesting.  I tend to cut @G.Grothendieck slack on this one, since the package has been around for a long time and I find it useful, even though I sometimes get grumpy at other package authors who I consider to be stealthily promoting their packages ...

Comment: @Thomas good call.  I must have overlooked or forgotten that info.  I asked because I often answer w/o disclosing this.  I will from now on.  It's natural to answer with tools your familiar with so I see no problem there but can see why disclosure is important too.

Comment: Thomas' link is referring to products and website promotion and is not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sprintf`:

```
> sprintf("chr%s",1:4)
[1] "chr1" "chr2" "chr3" "chr4"
```

Or `paste0`:

```
> paste0("chr",1:4)
[1] "chr1" "chr2" "chr3" "chr4"
```